# Inequality masquerading as equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Find all triples $(x,y,z)$ with $x,y,z \in (0,1)$ satisfying $$(x+\frac 1{2x}-1)(y+\frac1 {2y}-1)(z+\frac 1{2z}-1)=(1-\frac{xy}z)(1-\frac{yz}{x})(1-\frac{zx}{y})$$I took the LCM and simplified the inequality as follows $$(2x^2-2x+1)(2y^2-2y+1)(2z^2-2z+1)=8(x-yz)(y-xz)(z-xy)\\=>(x^2+[x-1]^2)(y^2+[y-1]^2)(z^2+[z-1]^2)=8(x-yz)(y-zx)(z-xy)$$ Now I think that the following inequality would help, but how? $$(x-yz+y-zx)(y-zx+z-xy)(z-xy+x-yz)\ge8(x-yz)(y-zx)(z-xy)\\=>(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)\ge 8(x-yz)(y-zx)(z-xy)$$ Please give a detailed solution.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it may be that your last line made the downvoter as sad as it made me. IMHO the best way to train for a math competitions is to think hard about problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sonnhard observed $x=y=z=1/2$ is the only solution. You are also correct that this is an inequality in disguise.

Consider the second form of your equation (the one you got by multiplying both sides with $8xyz$). The left hand side clearly achieves the minimum value $1/8$ at $x=y=z=1/2$.

Let's try to find the maximum of the right hand side $8(x-yz)(y-xz)(z-xy)$. Let's give $x$ a fixed value $\in(0,1)$. Let us concentrate on the set of combinations $(y,z)$ such that $yz$ has a fixed value, say $yz=k$. The product of the latter two factors is then
$$
(y-xz)(z-xy)=yz-x(z^2+y^2)+x^2yz=k(1+x^2)-x(z^2+y^2).
$$
By AM-GM we have $z^2+y^2\ge2\sqrt{z^2y^2}=2k$, so this product is $\le k(1-x)^2$ with equality, iff $z=y$. So if $x-k>0$, then the maximum of the right hand side can only be achieved at a point where $y=z$.

For the r.h.s. to be positive it is necessary that at least one of the coordinates is $>$ than the product of other two. By symmetry we can thus assume that the inequality $x-k>0$ holds at one of the maximums, and that $y=z$. This latter fact allows us to concentrate on the function
$$
(x-y^2)(y-yx)(y-yx)=y^2(x-y^2)(1-x)^2.
$$
If we view this as a function of $y$ only, we can ignore the last factor. The sum of the first two factors is $x$, so another application of AM-GM tells us that the maximum is attained at the point where $y^2=x/2$. This leaves you a univariate function that I'm sure you can handle. The conclusion is that the r.h.s. attains its maximum value $1/8$ also at the point $x=y=z=1/2$. The claim follows from this.

Comment: I don't really enjoy these inequality puzzles very much, so I don't know much about them, and standard tricks may help here more. Thankfully they were not a popular type of problems, when I was competing.